# s3 putObject access denied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have full permission to my s3 User login:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no group policy attached to this user.
But when I give putObject() command from my java program, I receive Access Denied message.
What can be the issue. As I told my user login has administrator access as well as AmazonS3FullAccess. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the issue resolved. 
It was not about firewall or permissions settings as I thought.
I was trying to do putObject on bucket which I should have created before doing this.
Inspite of saying no bucket found AWS gives a message Access Denied, which is wierd.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure whether your IP address is allowed or not. For Amazon Services, you can restrict access using IP addresses too. I had the same issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. please see this:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363006/php-amazon-sdk-s3-putobject-always-return-403)